# When should I break the fast for iftar when I can hear multiple adhans at different times?

Tags: ramadan, adhan, iftar

I live in an area where there are multiple masjids in the vicinity. Adhan can be heard from all the masjids, but the adhans are called at different times. The last one I hear is almost after the completion of first adhan I hear. In such a situation which adhan should I consider for making and breaking fast?

Currently I am relying on the first adhan which I hear and it is not from the nearest masjid. But it's the Juma masjid I go to on Fridays.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should go talk with those masajid imams about this issue too that why is this time difference. There can be one reason which i can understand is the jaafri fiqh(or shia) iftar 10 minutes late. But i don;t think azaan usually take 10 minutes anyway.

**Basically you are not supposed to iftar on azaan, but on timing calculated by credible sources for suhoor and iftaar.**

So, get a credible calendar, check your time against standard time and just follow your calendar. You can also check which majid is saying azaan on base of that calendar on time, and than follow that masjid's azaan.